# how to Runnable get selected sql also by nameValuepair

Tags: java, php, android

I am setting up a login fragment. How I can get the remain jsonObject by using nameValuepair. Then, show in TextView or using the SharedPreferences to share the jsonObject to other Fragment.

This is my php select statement.

"SELECT student_name, student_email, student_phone, student_id, student_pw
    FROM Student WHERE 
            student_id = '$student_id'
        AND student_pw = '$student_pw'";

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_loging_fragment, container,
            false);

    userName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTest);



    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    login();
                    passData();
                }
            }).start();

        }

    });
    return view;
}

public void passData(){

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              JSONObject json = getData(url);

              try{
                  JSONObject userEmail = json.getJSONObject("student_email");
                  JSONObject userPhone = json.getJSONObject("student_phone");

                  Log.v("myLog", "[USEREMAIL ] : " + userEmail.toString());
                  Log.v("myLog", "[USERPHONE ] : " + userPhone.toString());

              }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
}

   public static JSONObject getData(String url){

        JSONObject jArray = null;

        try
        {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("student_id", userName
                    .getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("student_pw", password
                    .getText().toString().trim()));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    responseHandler);

            Log.v("myLog", " [ PASSDATA ]");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("myLog", "[Network Error] :" + e.toString());
        }
        return jArray;
    }

public void login() {

    try {

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("student_id", userName
                .getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("student_pw", password
                .getText().toString().trim()));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                responseHandler);



        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.gla_there_come,
                        R.anim.gla_there_gone);

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textView.setText("Result : " + response);
                Log.v("myLog", "[RESPONSE] :" + response);
            }
        });

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")) {

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.v("myLog", "[LOGIN] :" + " SUCCESS");
                }
            });
            UserProfileFragment userProfile = new UserProfileFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, userProfile).commit();

            SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity()
                    .getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);
            editor.putString("nameIdentify", userName.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("pwIdentify", password.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            Log.v("myLog", "[PUT USERNAME] :" + userName.getText().toString());
            Log.v("myLog", "[PUT USERPESS] :" + password.getText().toString());
            Log.v("myLog", "[hasLoggedIn ]: false");

        } else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("No Such User Found")) {
            Log.v("myLog", "[LOGIN] :" + " FAIL");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("myLog", "[ERROR] :" + e.toString());
    }
}
```